# Replacing tags in HtmlAgility

Tags: html-agility-pack

I'm trying to replace all of my `h1` tags with `h2` tags and I'm using HtmlAgility pack.

I did this:

```
var headers = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h1");
if (headers != null)
{
    foreach (HtmlNode item in headers)
    {
        //item.Replace??
    }
}
```

and i got stuck there. I've tried this:

```
var headers = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h1");
if (headers != null)
{
    foreach (HtmlNode item in headers)
    {
        HtmlNode newNode = new HtmlNode(HtmlNodeType.Element, doc, item.StreamPosition);
        newNode.InnerHtml = item.InnerHtml;
        // newNode suppose to set to h2
        item.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(newNode, item);
    }
}
```

problem there is that i have no idea how to create a new h2, get all the attributes etc.
i'm sure theres a simple way to do that, any ideas?

Answer (score 14):

```
var headers = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h1");
        if (headers != null)
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode item in headers)
            {
                item.Name = "h2"
            }
        }
```

Comment: continuing my adventure exploring HtmlAgilityPack.. is there a way to force all attributes to be wrapped in double quotes?
i've found 'OptionOutputOptimizeAttributeValues' but that just removes all quotes..

Comment: I don't know. Try to ask in HtmlAgilityPack official forum. http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions

Comment: I'm also trying to change headers, and using this exact code. I can change the name, to "h2", but the "OuterHtml" is still an h1?

Answer (score 1):

A similar approach replacing the tags using Descendants instead of SelectNodes:

```
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> tagDescendants = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("h1");
foreach (HtmlNode htmlNode in tagDescendants)
{
    htmlNode.Name = "h2";
}
```