# Replace an html image element with a video element

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

I need to turn this:

```
<img id="xz123" src="Metadata_Media" alt="MediaFiles/xz123.mp4" />
```

into this:

I figure I could walk through the string with the help of HtmlAgilityPack like this:

```
Dim doc As New HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml(data)

Dim ImgElement = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img")

Dim pathString As HtmlAttribute = ImgElement.Attributes("alt")
Dim newPath As String = pathString.Value

Dim imgSrc As HtmlAttribute = ImgElement .Attributes("src")

If imgSrc.Value.Contains("Metadata_Media") Then
    imgSrc.Value = newPath
End If
```

Using the above image element, I think this code would replace this:

```
src="Metadata_Media"
```

with this:

```
src="MediaFiles/xz123.mp4"
```

But I'm not sure how to turn `<img` into `<video`

Can anyone help me out?

thanks!

Comment: Instead of changing it, can't you just remove the img element completely and append a new video element to the same parent?

Comment: @ChaseRocker there might be an instance where I need to do this to a bunch of different image tags and it would be easier to loop through them using the HtmlAgilityPack ....I think

Comment: try `ImgElement.name = "video"`...as suggested in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936116/replacing-tags-in-htmlagility